# How can I know IP address of FreeRadius server?

Tags: linux, wifi, radius, freeradius

Do I have to configure it in **FreeRadius** or does it have some default value?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the listen section of a virtual server or in radiusd.conf.  The config item you need to change is ipaddr.  By default the server will bind to all IP addresses on the system.

If you need to get the IP address the packet was received on, you can use `%{Packet-Dst-IP-Address}` in the policy language

Answer (score 0):

Well it should be the IP address of the box where Freeradius is installed

Answer (score 0):

You can set it this way, while starting radius server itself: /usr/sbin/radiusd -X -p 1816 -i 12.0.0.100
this 12.100 will remain as your server IP.